# Velocity hasNext method

Tags: velocity

I am attempting to invoke the `hasNext` method in a Velocity template, in order to effect behavior based on the position in a foreach loop - only `hasNext` is not working as documented.

Here is a snippet from the Velocity user guide, on the use of `hasNext`:

> Velocity also now provides an easy way to tell if you are on the last iteration of a loop:

```
#foreach( $customer in $customerList )
  $customer.Name#if( $foreach.hasNext ),#end
#end
```

Here is my version:

```
#foreach ($nav_item in $priNavItems)
  ...
  #if ( $foreach.hasNext )
    <img alt="" class="dive" src="/olp-theme/images/custom/dive.png">
  #end
#end
```

Has anyone been successful in invoking this method in a `#foreach` loop in a Velocity template? Perhaps under a different name (like `$velocityCount` for count)?

Any/all advice and or direction appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Which velocity version do you use?

Comment: i don't see this kind of method call in the docs: http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference-guide.html#aforeach_-_Loops_through_a_list_of_objects ! so what is the error that you are seeing? there is a `$foreach.count` and i guess that it is a simple back-reference to teh iterator in the loop, so that you "could" call `hasNext` on it.

Comment: The version of velocity used is 1.6.3 (from the manifest), and is embedded in the code base for the Liferay open source portal platform.  The online docs for velocity make reference to the hasNext method here:  http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#Loops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not supported in Velocity 1.6.3; the `$foreach.hasNext` functionality is provided by the `ForeachScope` class of 1.7+ ([docs](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/directive/ForeachScope.html)).

The online docs refer to the current version; when working with earlier versions you need to refer to that specific version's docs.